# eclipse, pydev, easy_install-ed eggs problem

Tags: python, eclipse

I have a problem with eclipse and easy_install'ed packages into virtualenv.
If I have

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads
```

import statement and put mouse cursor on "load" I get message

```
loads Found at: __module_not_in_the_pythonpath__
```

and it repeats with any module on `PYTHONPATH` while I have not manually add it to the `Project properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> External Libraries` :/
Like `~/Work/Environments/Default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-1.0-py2.6.egg` or any other egg pkg dir... `~/Work/Environments/Default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` is added but eclipse can't see any eggs inside it!

Python interpreter is set to `~/Work/Environments/Default/bin/python2.6`

I use eclipse-SDK-3.7M5-linux-gtk with latest PyDev.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Does the program run correctly?

Comment: Yes. And imports from eclipse python console too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you add a package after configuring the interpreter in Eclipse, you need to configure the interpreter again

See [PyDev's manual](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#what-if-i-add-something-new-in-my-system-pythonpath-after-configuring-it):

> If you add something to your python
>   installation, you need to either add
>   it manually as a 'new folder' in the
>   System PYTHONPATH (if it's still not
>   under a folder in the PYTHONPATH) or
>   (recommended) remove your interpreter
>   and add it again, then, press apply.

Note that adding the libraries in the project settings is not the recommended approach - it should be used only for some explicit additional library that is not in the standard PYTHONPATH but is used in a specific application.