# Unresolved import error with pydev while using from-import-as

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse with PyDev I get an `Unresolved import: pilImage` error while having this code.

The code works well when executed from inside PyDev or shell, but the IDE is high-lighting me this as an error.

```
from PIL import Image as pilImage
# do something with pilImage
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be a bit of a misunderstanding on how PIL should be used...

PIL has a rather uncommon packaging, in which the PIL library is added to the PYTHONPATH (and not the directory containing it), so, if you install with easy-install, it'll do something as:

```
/Lib
/Lib/site-packages
/Lib/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-win32.egg
/Lib/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-win32.egg/Image.py
```

So, the import that should actually be done is: **import Image as pilImage** (i.e.: no from PIL in the import).

A reference backing up that this is how the import should be: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

And in this case, the directory added to the PYTHONPATH should be: "/Lib/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-win32.egg"

Note that your import could work if you renamed the directory **/Lib/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-win32.egg** to **/Lib/site-packages/PIL** and just left **/Lib/site-packages/** in the PYTHONPATH (in which case you still would need to go to the PyDev interpreter configuration and just press apply so that it finds out that a new PIL package was added to the PYTHONPATH -- **note that in this case /Lib/site-packages/PIL should NOT be added to the PYTHONPATH**)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install PIL as an egg after installing PyDev? If so, PyDev won't know it's there. Remove and re-add the interpreter to fix this. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181160/eclipse-pydev-easy-install-ed-eggs-problem) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your PyDev-configured interpreter knows the PIL-package and it's contents?
If you configured your PyDev Python-interpreter before you installed the PIL-packages, it doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: I'm sure, if it wouldn't be it would fail to run. I suspect that this bug is the cause https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3439666&group_id=85796&atid=577329

Comment: does the proposed solution work? because how the interpreter runs has nothing to do how it is configured for eclipse/pydev. pydev requires configuration only for itself. f.e. the autosuggestion-features. if you execute the current script through the pydev-ui, the real interpreter is used.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes PyDev requires you to restart Eclipse in order to correct the wrong error message. It's often caused when a user writes the import before adding the module.